# Django ModelSelect2MultipleWidget for ManyToMany field

Tags: django, widget, jquery-select2, multipleselection

I have defined in my model a service which uses one or more articles. Therefore, i use a manytomany relationship. This is my model.py

```
class Artikel(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(unique=True, primary_key=True)
    artikel_typ = models.IntegerField(unique=False, default=0)
    bezeichnung = models.TextField(max_length=50)
    menge = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    preis = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    einheit = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.bezeichnung

class Leistung(models.Model):
    id = models.TextField(unique=True,primary_key=True)
    bezeichnung = models.TextField()
    dauer = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)  # This field type is a guess.
    preis = models.FloatField()  # This field type is a guess.
    artikel = models.ManyToManyField(Artikel,null=True, unique=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.bezeichnung
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'leistung'
```

I defined the form where i add a new service as follows:

```
class AddNewServiceForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    artikel_dd = Artikel.objects.all()

    model = Leistung
    fields = '__all__'
    widgets = {'id':forms.TextInput(attrs={'id': 'id', 'name': 'id', 'type': 'text', 'class': 'form-control',
               'data-val-required': 'Bitte tragen Sie eine 4MyHealth ID ein!', 'aria-required': 'true',
               'aria-invalid': 'false', }),
        'bezeichnung': forms.TextInput(
        attrs={'id': 'bezeichnung', 'name': 'bezeichnung', 'type': 'text', 'class': 'form-control',
               'data-val-required': 'Bitte tragen Sie eine Bezeichnung ein!', 'aria-required': 'true',
               'aria-invalid': 'false', }),
        'dauer': forms.TextInput(
            attrs={'id': 'dauer', 'name': 'dauer', 'type': 'number', 'step': '0.01', 'class': 'form-control',
                   'data-val-required': 'Bitte tragen Sie die Dauer ein!', 'aria-required': 'true',
                   'aria-invalid': 'false', }),
        'preis': forms.TextInput(
            attrs={'id': 'preis', 'name': 'preis', 'type': 'number', 'step': '0.01', 'class': 'form-control',
                   'data-val-required': 'Bitte tragen Sie die Dauer ein!', 'aria-required': 'true',
                   'aria-invalid': 'false', }),
        'artikel': ModelSelect2MultipleWidget(queryset=Artikel.objects.all(),attrs={'id': 'artikel', 'name': 'artikel_dropdown',
                                                            'aria-required': 'false',
                                                            'aria-invalid': 'false', }),

    }
```

and the template looks something like the following snippet (i won't post it all cause it's a lot):

```
        {% load static %}
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    
    {% block javascript %}
        <script type="text/javascript">
    
    
        </script>
    {% endblock %}
    {% block jquery %}
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
    
        </script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    {% endblock %}
    
    <script src="{% static 'django_select2/django_select2.js' %}"></script>
    
    <link href="/static/website/js/select2.min.js" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="/static/website/js/select2.min.js"></script>
    <head>
        {% include 'head.html' %}
    
        <!--Leistungen -->
        {% load static %}
    
    <body class="animsition">
    
    <div class="page-wrapper">
    
    
        {% include 'sidebar.html' %}
    
        <!-- PAGE CONTAINER-->
        <div class="page-container">
...
            <div class="row form-group">

              <label class="label mb-1">Verfügbare Artikel:</label>
                {{ forms.artikel }}
              </div>
....
```

So when i add the {{ forms.artikel }} the field appears, but there is no data inside. When i type something in the field, i get errors in the console: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found).

[image]

What am I missing?/What am I doing wrong? How could i solve this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

So after some struggles and lots of "try everything till it works" I got it! There are two things i did and they work:

1. Used Select2.js: install it with pip in your venv
2. when defining the widgets: use Select2MultipleWidget (stress on Widget!!!) and it works fine!

Glad to help anyone if they need help with this!